# Using PowerShell Calculated Properties from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, select

So I want to execute PowerShell Calculated Properties (I hope that's the correct name) from C#.

My CmdLet in the PS (Exchange) Console looks like this:

```
Get-Something -ResultSize unlimited |Select-Object DisplayName,@{name="RenamedColumn;expression={$_.Name}},ToBeExpanded -Expand ToBeExpanded |Select-Object DisplayNameRenamedColumn,ToBeExpandedGuid
```

This works just fine, the problem occures when I try to execute it from C#.

My Code looks like this:

```
List<string> parameters = new List<string>()
            {
                "DisplayName","@{{name=\"RenamedColumn\";expression={{$_.Name }} }}","ToBeExpanded"
            };
List<string> parameters2 = new List<string>()
            {
                "DisplayName","RenamedColumn","ToBeExpanded","ToBeExpandedGuid"
            };
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Something");
    powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize","unlimited");
    powershell.AddCommand("Select-Object");
    powershell.AddParameter("Property",parameters);
    powershell.AddParameter("ExpandProperty","ToBeExpanded");
    powershell.AddCommand("Select-Object");
    powershell.AddParameters("Property",parameters2);

    result = powershell.Invoke();
```

My result then contains the empty `ToBeExpandedGuid` (null). So I tried the command without the second select and it shows me that it has the column:

```
@{{name=\"RenamedColumn\";expression={{$_.Name }} }}
```

So my thought was that powershell doesn't recognize this renaming... Now my question how do I use something like this from C#? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell `@{Name="RenamedColumn";Expression={$_.Name}}` is not a string but a `Hashtable`, so in C# you also have to create a `Hashtable` (or other collection implementing `IDictionary`) to pass it to `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
new Hashtable{
    {"Name","RenamedColumn"},
    {"Expression",ScriptBlock.Create("$_.Name")}
}
```

P.S.
If all you want is a renaming, then you does not need `ScriptBlock` here:

```
@{Name="RenamedColumn";Expression="Name"}

new Hashtable{
    {"Name","RenamedColumn"},
    {"Expression","Name"}
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you!! It solved the problem:)

Comment: So I have another similar problem. In this case I need a script block : `@{name=someName;expression={$_.SomeColumn.Child -join ','}}`  but this won't work with the ScriptBlock...My C# Code looks like the following:
`new Hashtable(){ 
{"Name", "someName"},
{"Expression",ScriptBlock.Create("$_.SomeColumn.Child -join ','")}
}`

Comment: @RaphaelFischer I does not see a problem with your C# code. What exactly problem is? Exception, unexpected result or something else? Could you provide code to reproduce the issue ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to describe the result:D
The result gives me PSObjects with the property "someName" and the according value null. So it seems that powershell selects the Name part of the calculated property but the expression part seems to make problems... The error and warning stream of the powershell are empty

Comment: @RaphaelFischer Does input object really have `SomeColumn` and subsequent `Child` properties? I can recommend to you to enable strict mode `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`, so referencing to not existing property cause error.

Comment: Yes the input does defintily contain the child I'm looking for.
In the mean time I've tried the second part of your answer (renaming with the ScriptBlock) and this didn't work as well... so it must be a problem with the scriptblock ?

Comment: `Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize unlimited |Select-Object -Property @{Name="NameRename";Expres
sion={$_.Name}},DisplayName,Guid,ManagedBy -expand ManagedBy |Select-Object @{Name="ObjectGuid";Expression={$_.ManagedBy
 -join ','}},DisplayName,Guid,NameRename -unique`This is the comand from the PowerShell it works just fine.

Comment: @RaphaelFischer Really, does not see anything wrong with your code and does not have Exchange to directly try it. I thing, you better ask a new question to get better exposure.

Answer (score 0):

@PetSerAl

This code down below should reproduce my error :

```
         List<object> parameters = new List<object>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    new Hashtable()
                    {
                        {"Name","someName"},
                        {"Expression",ScriptBlock.Create("$_.SomeColumn.Child -join ','")}
                    }
                };
            powershell.AddCommand("Get-Something");
            powershell.AddCommand("Select-Object");
            powershell.AddParameter("Property", parameters);

            powershell.Runspace.Open();
            Collection<PSObject> powershellResult = powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Runspace.Close();
```

My code works dynamically so you can't see which command is produced (except in debugging...)